# Re-rendering the view without reloading/refreshing the AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The application I'm working on right now contains lots of ng-include directive and I hate to reload the whole application just to see an HTML update.

I've tried Replaying the XHR manually using the Network and it gets back the updated HTML View but definitely, it doesn't get reflected in the DOM.

[image]

What I am searching for is a way that all the HTML views get fetched again without me hitting the reload button.

It can be a browser extension or a code snippet (which I'll turn into a browser extension to be used for others) or any other sane way.

Answer (score 0):

Check *disable cache* checkbox on *network* page and then try *replay XHR*. I can't see why you don't want to reload the whole page but whatever.

Comment: _Replay XHR_ doesn't impact the application. It'll bring the latest updates but it'll only stay in the Developer Tools.
I want the HTML to be re-rendered without all the data APIs being called again..

Comment: Try to use a function that gets the specific part of the page that you wish to reload as an argument and requests a reload only for this.